# how to scroll a page at specific position when page reloads in MVC ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is ASP.NET MVC project, I have placed a `div` at specific position in the page and added id `dealProductAnchor`. When this page loads or reloads normally it behaves as normal, but when a specific button is clicked **I want that page after completing all postback progress when page loads done**, it comes to the position of that div.

with java script I tried this, but did nothing any solution from server side or client side will be appreciable.

```
$(".button-1").click(function () {
        if (localStorage && !localStorage.getItem('click')) {
            localStorage.setItem('click', true);
        }
    });


$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('click') == true) {

        window.location = window.location.href + "#dealProductAnchor";
        //click = false;
    }
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to Achieve this via BackEnd you Can set a value into `ViewBag` and check it on `.cshtml` page like below:

**Controller Code :**

```
 public ActionResult TextAction() {
// Do your Logic here
        ViewBag.testValue = "test";
        return View();
    }
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
@if (ViewBag.testValue == "test") {
        <text>$('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($("#dealProductAnchor").offset().top) - 200
        }, 'slow');</text>
    }
});
```

hope it helps you :)

Comment: this will bring me all the time when I visit that page, I just want when button is clicked. I will not click everytime

Comment: ok then you can skip `$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".button-1").trigger("click");
 });` this block. After that when you click on button-1 the page will scroll to perticular div.

Comment: when I click on a button it performs some back-end operations and reloads the page, when reload finishes I want that position then. above code will take me there before the page loads

Comment: How do you call your back end operation? Show the code

Comment: Although I had to adjust it to my situation, this answer led me to the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this??

```
$(".button-1").click(function () {
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#dealProductAnchor").offset().top
    }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: this will bring me before the page loads, I want that location after page loads

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting:

```
window.location = window.location.href + "#dealProductAnchor";
```

In your `$(document).ready` callback, set the scrolltop using Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('click') == true) {
        $('body').scrollTop($("#dealProductAnchor").offset().top)
        localStorage.removeItem('click');
    }
});
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to add a `window.setTimeout()` wrapper to allow the browser to finish rendering:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('click') == true) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('body').scrollTop($("#dealProductAnchor").offset().top);
        });
        localStorage.removeItem('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: tried both. in console, click is set to true, but when `$(document).ready(function ()` call starts, it is not going inside the if block, even localStorage is true

Comment: Ahh... wait, the result of getItem is always a string! Your check should be: localStorage.getItem('click') == "true"

Answer (score 0):

I'd try changing the form action attribute to include the hash

```
$(".button-1").click(function () {
    //Change $("form") to use the form ID if you have one
    $("form").attr("action", $("form").attr("action") + "#dealProductAnchor" );
}
```

If the button is submitting the form you may need to change the button from submit to button then submit the form in the click handler.